# I was watching The Simpsons when Milhouse Van Houten says “Quote, unquote', but I don’t understand. Please have a look

Tags: phrase-meaning

The world is or rather the expression is quote,unquote.

The sentence that Mulhouse said was "Get a load of that quote-unquote Santa."

It was an episode where Homer get the job of Santa for Christmas. And Bart and their friends glimpse The Santa (who is Homer in reality) but Bart didn't knew it and he was going to humiliated his dad...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quote unquote (or end-quote), unseparated by the actual quotation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364288/quote-unquote-or-end-quote-unseparated-by-the-actual-quotation) (here the equivalent of _scare quotes_: "Get a load of that quote-unquote Santa" = "Get a load of that 'Santa' " = "Get a load of that – is he supposed to be a _Santa_?!") (a later answer in the duplicate)

Comment: Thank you , thanks to you I  have  understand.

Comment: If we'd just follow [Victor's lead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJiHlt8NRqk) phht phht phht